# Magento Community 1.9 HTTPS redirect loop with Cloudflare

Tags: magento, loops, redirect, cloudflare

I've pushed my website's DNS through Cloudflare and is now experiencing redirect loops when accessing admin and checkout pages.

The redirect is - http://postimg.org/image/ehq0kjcw1/

My Magento setup

1. Community 1.9
2. Cache management has been disabled
3. Index management has also disabled
4. Clear all cache

I've followed every steps (except step 4 about restoring visitor IP) mentioned in [Cloudflare's article](http://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203904600-Using-CloudFlare-with-Magento), but I am still having the redirect loop problem. Here are [my cloudflare page rules](http://postimg.org/image/omcgjh6hn/).

This redirect loop problem occurs **with or without Cloudflare flexible SSL turned on.**

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you update your Magento store domains? Have a look at the database table "core_config_data" within the paths "web/secure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url" and try to enter just the HTTP url for both values at first to make your shop up and running, before configuring HTTPS.

Comment: No I didn't update my Magento store domains. So this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server supports SSL, you should generally use Full SSL instead of flexible:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-

This ensures you don't have any weird redirect logic taking place with CloudFlare, since Flexible SSL redirects HTTPS requests to HTTP at the backend.

Comment: copying snippets or references helps others quickly assess the quality of the answer, and go to a single place.  You may consider copying the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten an excellent and simple answer from Cloudflare support.

I just need to simply **use Full SSL instead** of Flexible SSL.

Printscreen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWl0Y.png

I think my Magento has a secure base URL defined and it tries and redirects to HTTPS when I access a secure page.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a redirect loop by having conflicting redirects on your server and/or with PageRules.

Example:
You have one redirect saying send domain.com to www.domain.com, then you have another redirect saying send www.domain.com to domain.com.

If you have access to terminal on your computer, then try running this command to see what is returned in the location field on the URL the error happens on:

curl -v http://yourdomain.com (replace with the actual URL).

Comment: This is not the problem since the admin link worked before I push the DNS through Cloudflare. My www.domain.com will go to www.domain.com and domain.com will go to www.domain.com